# Writing MEMO-field in DBF table by PHP

Tags: php, dbf, memo

PHP extension dbase not support read/write operations with DBF files. Are there any third-party solutions (libraries, classes) for writing data in the field MEMO?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know much about dbase, but wondering if using PHP's PDO would work instead then.

Might be worth experimenting.

This will point you in direction: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-dblib.php

Answer (score 0):

you can use odbc_connect using Microsoft foxPro driver to connect to a dbf database and perform a CRUD query operations. you can use odbc_exec()